# React JSX boolean condition causing sonar cognitive complexity

Tags: reactjs, sonarqube

I am getting sonarqube error for cognitive complexity of functions. I am using react{boolean && syntax in most of the jsx and it is showing cognitive complexity after a sonarqube scan.Is there any other better way to write it so that I can fix sonarqube issue. My sample syntax is below.

```
{loadStatus === 'success' && (<customtag> Sampletext </customtag>)}  
{loadStatus === 'error' && (<customtag2> Sampletext </customtag2>)}
{loadStatus === 'loading' && (<customtag3> Sampletext </customtag3>)}
{projStatus === 'success' && (<projcustomtag> Sampletext </projcustomtag>)}
{someOtherStatus === 'fetching' && (<somecustomtag> Sampletext </somecustomtag>)}
```

I am using the above syntax in one page (more than 15 occurrences)which is giving me the issue. Every AND operation is considered as +1 complexity. Is there a way, I can modify the syntax to avoid the sonar error.

Comment: This is around the 4th or 5th question I've seen today on this alone, I wonder has some recent update to sonarqube triggered this? I don't see any overt ways to simplify this code or reduce the complexity (*and to be honest it isn't all that hard to read/reason about*). Each line is a different and unique line.

Answer (score 0):

i think better for all ' if ' you need put in function

but  you most use in jsx  :

```
{loadStatus === 'success' ?  'this is ok' : null}
{loadStatus === 'error' ?  'you have error' : null}
{loadStatus === 'loading' ?  'loading' : null}
```

---

```
{loadStatus === 'success' ? <div> this is ok </div> : null}
```